# how to parse integer from a long string

Tags: java, android, string, int

I want to parse two values from a string in android studio. 
I cannot change the data type from web so I need to parse an Intt.The string that I receive from web is
5am-10am.

How can I get these values i.e. 5 and 10 from the string "5am-10am".
Thanks in advance for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the code below shows step by step how to parse the format you are given. I also added in the steps to use the newly parsed Strings as ints so you can perform arithmetic on them. Hope this helps.

```
        `/*Get the input*/
        String input = "5am-10am"; //Get the input

        /*Separate the first number from the second number*/
        String[] values = input.split("-"); //Returns 'values[5am, 10am]'

        /*Not the best code -- but clearly shows what to do*/
        values[0] = values[0].replaceAll("am", ""); 
        values[0] = values[0].replaceAll("pm", "");
        values[1] = values[1].replaceAll("am", "");
        values[1] = values[1].replaceAll("pm", "");

        /*Allows you to now use the string as an integer*/
        int value1 = Integer.parseInt(values[0]);
        int value2 = Integer.parseInt(values[1]);

        /*To show it works*/
        int answer = value1 + value2;
        System.out.println(answer); //Outputs: '15'`
```

Comment: good one dude thanks.. other answers were also may be correct but i found this anwer easy and tried this at first

Answer (score 1):

its work only this kind of format "Xam-Yam".

```
String value="5am-10am";
value.replace("am","");
value.replace("pm","");//if your string have pm means add this line
String[] splited = value.split("-");


  //splited[0]=5
  //splited[1]=10
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the trick you should use:-

```
String timeValue="5am-10am";
String[] timeArray = value.split("-");
// timeArray [0] == "5am";
// timeArray [1] == "10am";

timeArray [0].replace("am","");
// timeArray [0] == "5";// what u needed

timeArray [1].replace("am","");
// timeArray [1] == "10"; // what u needed
```

Answer (score 0):

I will use some `regex` to remove the other String and leave only the numeric data. sample code below:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    String sampleStr = "5am-10pm";
    String[] strArr = sampleStr.split("-"); // I will split first the two by '-' symbol.

    for(String strTemp : strArr) {
        strTemp = strTemp.replaceAll("\\D+",""); // I will use this regex to remove all the string leaving only numbers.
        int number = Integer.parseInt(strTemp);
        System.out.println(number);
    }

}
```

The advantages of this is you don't need to specifically remove "am" or "pm" because all of the other character will be remove and the numbers will only be left.

Answer (score 0):

I think that this way can be the faster. Please consider that the regex doesn't validates so it will parse values as "30am-30pm" for example. Validation comes apart.

```
final String[] result = "5am-10pm".replaceAll("(\\d)[pa]m", "$1").split("-");
System.out.println(result[0]); // -- 5
System.out.println(result[1]); // -- 10
```